# If $X, Y$ and $Z$ are non identical and independent exponential random variables, what is the probability density function of $X + Y - Z$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Nothing to add at this point, I get what $X + Y$ PDF is but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of two independent Exponential Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174922/sum-of-two-independent-exponential-random-variables)

Comment: No, it doesn't, it answers the question "PDF of X + Y" (that I know)

Comment: Hint: $X + Y - Z\equiv X + Y + (-Z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X,\,Y$ have different means, the characteristic function is$$\frac{1}{(1-i\mu_Xt)(1-i\mu_Yt)(1+i\mu_Zt)}=\frac{A_X}{1-i\mu_Xt}+\frac{A_Y}{1-i\mu_Yt}+\frac{B_Z}{1+i\mu_Zt}$$(coefficients are an exercise), so the PDF of $W:=X+Y-Z$ is$$\frac{A_X}{\mu_X}\exp(-w/\mu_X)[w\ge0]+\frac{A_Y}{\mu_Y}\exp(-w/\mu_Y)[w\ge0]-\frac{B_Z}{\mu_Z}\exp(w/\mu_Z)[w\le0].$$Feel free to instead parameterize the exponential distributions as $\lambda_X=\mu_X^{-1}$ etc. As for the case where $X,\,Y$ have the same mean, you can treat that in a similar way, using the fact that $\frac{1}{(1-\theta t)^2}$ is the characteristic function of a distribution with PDF $\frac{u}{\theta^2}\exp(-u/\theta)$ on $[0,\,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed (I don't know why this question has been closed, apparently you're more intelligent than those guys that were looking for "missing" details). However, can you give me some reference about the method that you used to get the PDF of W?

Comment: @Luigi2405 I started by noting the characteristic functions satisfy $\phi_{X+Y-Z}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)\phi_Z(-t)$. Next I used the fact that, because the PDF [is linear in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) the characteristic function, we can just use the exponential PDF. (Well, we have to reflect it for the last term, but that's easy.)

Comment: Thanks again. I computed the coefficients (I proved their correctness by the normalization condition) and then interpreted your result as a decaying exponential if w is negative and a sum of two exponentials if w is positive. Am I right?

Comment: @Luigu2405 Sorry, I left an errant sign there; now it's fixed. A PDF has to decay as $w\to\pm\infty$ so it can integrate to $1$.

Comment: Yes I've noticed but I thought there was a different notation that you used and of course I explained myself very badly. Very kind

Comment: I have another question. What is the CDF? I got the coefficients and what I obtained is indeed a PDF (I verified it by the normalization condition), then I integrated the two "side" of the PDF and got the CDF (I checked that it was a CDF using limits and again normalization conditions). Then I embedded it in my program and I always got a probability (a number between 0 and 1) but my simulations don't match my results. Therefore I don't know whether I made a mistake in the coefficients or in the computation of the CDF (or both). If you don't mind would you give me the CDF?

Comment: If you want I can provide you the coefficients and the CDF that I got

Comment: @Luigi2405 I bet I know what your mistake was. Your PDF is a linear combination of $1$-sided PDFs. Two of them are $0$ for $w<0$, so their contribution to the CDF would be too. An expression of the form $1-\exp -w/a$ with $a>0$ would actually be negative if $w<0$. Similarly, the third is $0$ for $w>0$.

Comment: Your bet is right. Then what should I do? I'm not a mathematician but these are notions that I'm sure I will use in my career and that therefore I want to know

Comment: @Luigi2405 Since you're coding the CDF, it comes down to if/else. Let's write your wrong CDF as `A+B+1-C`. Then you need `A+B if w>=0 else 1-C`, or whatever syntax is needed in your programming language.

Comment: Except for the 1-C I got to the same result but I add the integral on the whole negative w-axes if w is positive. In other words my C(and not 1-C) is the CDF of an exponential decaying on negative values of w scaled down by the coefficent that I computed previosly and my A+B is merely the weighted sum of two exponential decaying on positive values of w scaled down by their respective coefficients (plus the portion of integral on the negative w-axes). Where did I get wrong? Should I have just used  1-C rather than just C?

Comment: @Luigi2405 Whatever you call the third part, it needs to rise from $0$ at $w=-\infty$ to $1$ at all $w\ge0$ rather than continuing to grow past $1$ for $w>0$. You could even use `min(A+B, 0)+max(third part, 1)`.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try. Just to be sure, the sum of coefficients must be 1, right? However, thanks again for your attention

Comment: @Luigi2405 A linear combination of CDFs will need coefficients summing to $1$, yes, as can be deduced by considering the behaviour as $w\to\infty$.

Comment: Again results seem wrong to me. Can I ask you for the complete expression of the CDF, I don't know where I do wrong..

Comment: Are there any techniques that one can use to find the coefficients $A_X$, $A_Y$, $B_Z$ in a systematic way? Here, one can find them quite easily, but are there any methods, if one looks at the same problem with (many) more than three r.v.'s.?