# What is the probability density function of $X+Y-Z$, where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are three independent and non identical exponential random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Suppose that X, Y and Z are three exponential random variables, what is the probability density function of their combination X+Y-Z?

I've already asked for this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524822/if-x-y-and-z-are-non-identical-and-independent-exponential-random-variables/3524845) but, as you can see in the comments, when I'm programming the CDF I obtain results that are not acceptable

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $P_X(x)=\lambda_xe^{-x\lambda_x},P_Y(y)=\lambda_ye^{-y\lambda_y},P_Z(z)=\lambda_ze^{-z\lambda_z}$ and $x,y,z,\lambda_x,\lambda_y,\lambda_z\ge0$. We need $F_W(w) = \text{Pr}\{W\le w\}$ where $W = X+Y-Z$. Therefore for a given $W=w$, we have to integrate the 3-dimensional triangular polyhedron formed by the plane $X+Y-Z=W$ in the non-negative orthant. We have

$$F_W(w)=\text{Pr}\{X+Y-Z\le w\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{w+z}\int_{0}^{w-y+z}P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)dzdydx \\ = \int_{0}^{\infty}P_Z(z)dz\int_{0}^{w+z}P_Y(y)dy\int_{0}^{w-y+z}P_X(x)dx
$$

Where $P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = P_X(x)P_Y(y)P_Z(z)$ comes from the independence.

$$\Rightarrow F_W(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_ze^{-z\lambda_z}dz\int_{0}^{w+z}\lambda_ye^{-y\lambda_y}dy\int_{0}^{w-y+z}\lambda_xe^{-x\lambda_x}dx \\
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_ze^{-z\lambda_z}dz\int_{0}^{w+z}\lambda_ye^{-y\lambda_y}\left(-e^{-\lambda_x(w+z-y)}+1\right)dy \\ 
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_ze^{-z\lambda_z}\left[\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_x-\lambda_y}e^{-\lambda_x(w+z)} \left( -e^{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(w+z)} +1\right) + \left( 
-e^{-\lambda_y(w+z)}+1 \right)\right]dz \\
=1-\frac{\lambda_z}{\lambda_y+\lambda_z}e^{-\lambda_yw}+\frac{\lambda_y\lambda_z}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{-\lambda_xw} - \frac{\lambda_z\lambda_y}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_z+\lambda_y)}e^{-\lambda_yw} \\
=1+\frac{\lambda_y\lambda_z}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{-\lambda_xw}-\frac{\lambda_z\lambda_x}{(\lambda_y+\lambda_z)(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)}e^{-\lambda_yw}
$$

Finally from $f_W(w)=\frac{d}{dw}F_W(w)$ we have

$$f_W(w)=\frac{-\lambda_y\lambda_z\lambda_x}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{-\lambda_xw}+\frac{\lambda_y\lambda_z\lambda_x}{(\lambda_y+\lambda_z)(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)}e^{-\lambda_yw}\\
$$

This holds true when $w \ge 0$. When $w < 0$ we have

$$F_W(w)=\text{Pr}\{X+Y-Z\le w\}= \int_{-w}^{\infty}P_Z(z)dz\int_{0}^{w+z}P_Y(y)dy\int_{0}^{w-y+z}P_X(x)dx
$$

Which is similar to previous one and yields

$$F_W(w)=\int_{-w}^{\infty}\lambda_ze^{-z\lambda_z}\left[\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_x-\lambda_y}e^{-\lambda_x(w+z)} \left( -e^{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(w+z)} +1\right) + \left( 
-e^{-\lambda_y(w+z)}+1 \right)\right]dz\\
=e^{\lambda_zw}-\frac{\lambda_z}{\lambda_y+\lambda_z}e^{\lambda_zw}+\frac{\lambda_y\lambda_z}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{\lambda_zw} - \frac{\lambda_z\lambda_y}{(\lambda_x-\lambda_y)(\lambda_z+\lambda_y)}e^{\lambda_zw}\\
=\frac{\lambda_x\lambda_y}{(\lambda_y+\lambda_z)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{\lambda_zw}
$$

Please notice that $x,y,z\ge0$ so when $w<0$ we must have $z \in [-w,\infty)$. Then we get

$$f_W(w) = \frac{\lambda_x\lambda_y\lambda_z}{(\lambda_y+\lambda_z)(\lambda_x+\lambda_z)}e^{\lambda_zw}$$

The MATLAB code to use this distribution as a function is presented below. The parameters $\lambda_x,\lambda_y,\lambda_z$ and the vector of required values for $f_W(w)$ i.e. $w$ are given and the value of distribution as a vector the same length of input $w$ will be returned.

```
function f_w = PDF_W(lambda_x,lambda_y,lambda_z,w)
    f_w = (w>=0).*(-lambda_x*lambda_y*lambda_z)/(lambda_x-lambda_y)/(lambda_x+lambda_z).*exp(-lambda_x.*w)+...
        (w>=0).*(lambda_x*lambda_y*lambda_z)/(lambda_x-lambda_y)/(lambda_y+lambda_z).*exp(-lambda_y.*w)+...
        (w<0).*(lambda_x*lambda_y*lambda_z)/(lambda_x+lambda_z)/(lambda_y+lambda_z).*exp(+lambda_z.*w);
end
```

Program for C.D.F. is as follows

```
function P_w = CDF_W(lambda_x,lambda_y,lambda_z,w)
    f_w = (w>=0)+(w>=0).*(*lambda_y*lambda_z)/(lambda_x-lambda_y)/(lambda_x+lambda_z).*exp(-lambda_x.*w)-...
        (w>=0).*(lambda_x*lambda_z)/(lambda_x-lambda_y)/(lambda_y+lambda_z).*exp(-lambda_y.*w)+...
        (w<0).*(lambda_x*lambda_y)/(lambda_x+lambda_z)/(lambda_y+lambda_z).*exp(+lambda_z.*w);
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But correct me If I'm wrong, but this holds just for positive w, right?

Comment: Awww, yep, you are right. The negative region must be integrated too, i forgot totally. Will edit soon.

Comment: Thanks very much. I noticed some (possible) errors on derivation by the way. $\lambda_x$ in the second exponent of the CDF becomes a $\lambda_z$ and it sign doesn't flip after derivation

Comment: Yes and the fact that $z$ ranges from $-w$ to infinity, i should revise it thoroughly, just need some time.

Comment: Ah ok that's ok, Thanks again!

Comment: Jesus, that was a medieval torture man, I'm happy its over now xD, please check and inform me if it's OK. Wish you the best.

Comment: I bet it was. Unfortunatelly I can't now, tomorrow morning (I'm in Italy) I'll get back to work and I'll inform you. Thanks, thanks and again thanks in any case

Comment: I just tested it and results in my simulation matches the prediction of your calculations. Thank you very much

Comment: Rectification: although prediction matches simulation your formulation should be symmetric with respect to $X$ and $Y$ but it isn't :/

Comment: Ehy. I generated random numbers as $X+Y-Z$ but the ratio between the number of negative samples over the number of total samples never matches what I expect from your CDF (that, btw, generate also number greater than 1). I also tried to do that myself but I got nothing useful. Can you revisit your answer please?

Comment: That and the fact that it's not symmetric with respect to $X$ and $Y$, I must check it again!

Comment: Thanks! Very gentle

Comment: That was a sign mistake, :[, that's embarrassing. It's correct now, thanks God at lats xD

Comment: Ok, not it makes perfectly sense but there is still one more problem. I'm sure that the formulation is right but look at this piece of code:

Comment: ```def my_dist(z, x, y, size):
    ar = []
    for i in range(size):
        ar.append(stats.expon.rvs(x) + stats.expon.rvs(y) - stats.expon.rvs(z))
    return np.array(ar)
def F_w(z, x, y, w):
    if w>=0:
        return 1 + y*z*np.exp(-1*x*w)/((x-y)*(x+z)) - x*z*np.exp(-1*y*w)/((x-y)*(y+z))
    return x*y*np.exp(z*w)/((y+z)*(x+z))```
If I run ```a = my_dist(100, 15, 20, size)``` and then ```len(a[a>0])/len(a)``` I expect  this last quantity be approximately ```F_w(100, 15, 20,0)``` but it isn't. Am I using your CDF wrongly? Thanks for your help, this is my last issue

Comment: Sorry but in the comments apparently is not possible to insert new lines inside a code section..

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, if it was MATLAB I would be able to help you much better. But one peculiar thing in your code that I noticed, is that for example in y*z*np.exp(-1*x*w)/((x-y)*(x+z)), x,y,z are supposed to be $\lambda_x,\lambda_y,\lambda_z$ and w be just the value of $w$. Should you first initialize the corresponding P.D.F.'s using scipy.stats.expon() for example x = expon.rvs(scale = $\lambda_x$) and then use them? Also I will add MATLAB code for this problem.

Comment: Yes, of course $x$, $y$ and $z$ are $λ_x$, $λ_y$ and $λ_z$, respectively. My first version of the code which tested the distributions was base on scipy distributions, then I switched to numpy as results were the same but I could get them more efficiently. By the way I just switched again to scipy world to make sure that results are the same and do not match the predictions. I give up ahaha